# Problem with reading a text file and getting length of each line, while simultaneously adding them to a string if of the right length

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner, string-length

So i'm trying to read a text file and trying to pick only the right length strings from it but every time i check for the length the filescanner skips a line. Is there a way to prevent this/or a different solution?

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(fileName);

File file = new File("path" + fileName);

fileScanner = new Scanner(file);

 String cache = "";
 while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
     if (fileScanner.nextLine().length() < 3){
         cache = cache + fileScanner.nextLine();
     }
 }
```

Comment: There are plenty of useful methods that you can try and see if it works, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: You call `nextLine()` twice for each line with `length < 3`.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling the `nextLine()` method twice in your code (once in your if-statement, and once when concatenating it to `cache`). You should only access it once and store it in a variable, like this:

```
while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
  if (line.length() < 3){
    cache = cache + line;
  }
}
```